# reverse selected text with vba word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to select some text in Word, for example "abcde fgh jkl" and reverse it with a macro and have it as "lkj hgf edcba"

i've found a javascript code for this, on [www.textreverse.com](http://www.textreverse.com) but couldn't make it work with vba, can anyone help? thanks in advance.

```
function reverse() {
   var value = document.myForm.myText.value;
   for (var text = '',i=value.length-1;i>-1;i=i-1)
       text += value.charAt(i);
   document.myForm.myText.value = text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the StrReverse function, or if you want to code.

```
Dim strStart as string
    dim strComplete as string
    dim I as integer

    strStart = "TESTING"

    for I = len(strstart) to 1 step -1
        strcomplete=strcomplete& mid(strStart,i,1)
    next I
```

I haven't tested this, but what you have with a VB for next, not javascript.

Comment: would this code work on older versions of ms-word? because i couldn't make it work on an older setup, even though it works normally on word 2013.

Comment: The full code version should.  How old are we talking?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to go through the hassle to write this function from scratch. There is a ready made built-in function for you.

```
Function ReverseText(MyText As String)
    ReverseText = StrReverse(MyText)
End Function
```

Comment: Selected text, would be `MyText`, so `strReversed = ReverseText(selectedtext)` for example.